# what is the best way to set a target location when making a unity level based game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

So I am making a game in unity, its a 3D level based game where the levels are loaded in using a text file.

**Example File:**

```
S 
P
MT
NP
NE
```

**Key:**

```
S - Starting platform
P - Normal platform
T - Target location
M - Moving platform
E - End platform
N - No platform
```

In this example level the player needs to move the cube from the 'S' to the 'E' but in order to do that they will have to move on top of the moving platform which will then move inline with the other platform for the player to complete the level.

No I am struggling to figure out the best way to set the target location when generating the levels, the first option i tried was to just use:

```
FindObject
```

but this is not the best options as later i might want to add multiple moving platform to the same level.

another option was to set the target point on the moving platform script when ever the moving platform is instantiated into the game but this doesn't seem to be working as it is created before the the target platform is created which is resulting to the platform not moving at all or it just moves to the very first position i set it to when first trying it out even though the target location changes from level to level.

Is there a better way to do this so that i can have the option of having multiple moving platforms in a single level.

This is an example level in the game [level image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc3PG.png) the bright blue platform is the moving platform which is supposed to move the the left when you move the cube on to it but at the moment it moves back to the very beginning of the level (bottom of the image)

Comment: It is unclear what you mean in your question.  Are you asking about prefabs?  References to instantiated prefabs?  Something else?  Wasn't sure what `FindObject` had to do with anything, so that made me think this is related to instance references.  What do you mean by target location?

Comment: yeah so all of the platforms are prefabs that get instantiated to create a level. the target location is the location the moving platform will (supposedly) move to when the player moves on to it. in this example level the moving platform will move one unity to the right. The findObject was a way to find the target location searching the scene looking for a game object with a targetlocation tag but this wont work if i want to have multiple moving platforms as they wont know which target location belongs to each moving platform

Comment: You should encode the movement into your definition file.  Something like `1r ` (1 unit to right) or `1f` (1 unit forward), then you can define the target point as that pieces position plus its motion.